# uploaded from Xcode 6 and can't find my app on iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I uploaded my app using Xcode 6.2. I clicked on validate, and there were no problems. Then, I clicked on submit, it told me the app was submitted but I can't find it in my iTunes connect Apps!

Comment: it may still in the processing statue. wait for about 5 minutes & check again

Comment: @BC_Dilum Thanks for your reply, i found it but it was uploaded in another Application on the iTunes connect, do you have a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload it with same account again. If you have uploaded with another account, then Apple should not allow you to upload because when you upload application to iTunes, it verifies your bundle ID and distribution profile and then only allow you to upload application on iTunes.

Comment: developer thanks for your answer, i found that it was being uploaded to iTunes connect but under another application. Do you know how to upload under the application name that i want ?

Comment: You need to add new application from account from which you want to upload application. Then you can submit with application from Xcode with new account.